# How to modify the currency filter, according to my currency symbol, Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
<div ng-init="qty=1;cost=2">
    <b>Invoice:</b>
    <div>
        Quantity: <input type="number" ng-model="qty" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        Costs: <input type="number" ng-model="cost" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <b>Total:</b> {{qty * cost | currency}} //may be change is required here
    </div>
</div>
```

This Results in :

[image]

like ₹, £, ¥

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this using the `symbol` parameter for the currency filter.

```
{{qty * cost | currency:"¥"}}
```

Check the reference: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency.